# Delete function tries to delete foreign key

Tags: java, database, orm, mapping, entity

I got the following problem.
When I try to delete my entity it automatically trys to delete the foreign key objects.

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class ScmoKomponente implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50, message = "{standard}")
    private String name;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date datum;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ScmoProjekt projekt;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private SupplierUser lieferant;

    public SupplierUser getLieferant() {
        return lieferant;
    }

    public void setLieferant(SupplierUser lieferant) {
        this.lieferant = lieferant;
    }

    public ScmoProjekt getProjekt() {
        return projekt;
    }

    public void setProjekt(ScmoProjekt projekt) {
        this.projekt = projekt;
    }

    public Date getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

    public void setDatum(Date datum) {
        this.datum = datum;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof ScmoKomponente)) {
            return false;
        }
        ScmoKomponente other = (ScmoKomponente) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "scmo.model.project.ScmoKomponente[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

The delete function:

```
public void deleteScmoKomponente(ScmoKomponente ScmoKomponente) {
    em.remove(em.merge(ScmoKomponente));
}
```

And the call:

```
public String deleteScmoKompo() {
    ss.deleteScmoKomponente(selectedKompo);
    selectedKompo = null;
    return scmoEditKompo();
}
```

When I now try to delete the scmoKomponent it automatically deletes the ScmoProjekt and the SupplierUser objects in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I know correctly if you set  `CascadeType.ALL` hibernate or jpa would be doing all operations with child elements like update, save, delete when you change your parent entity.
So if you want fix your program simply delete cascade attr from `@Many-to-One` annotation.

You can find some information about cascade types [here](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/10930_3559931_3/Hibernate-Basics.htm)